# Black Screen when attempting to use MPMoviePlayer

Tags: ios, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, movie

I am using MPMoviePlayer to display a video from an external URL onto my iPhone App, however when I run the App a black screen is all that shows. 
Here is the URL I am using:

```
2015-04-27 00:11:29.655 Floadt[21069:2598414] https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t50.2886-16/11179443_819874424728492_389701720_n.mp4
```

Here is my code to try to setup MPMoviePlayer:

```
if (entry[@"videos"] != nil) {
    NSLog(@"There is a Video: %@", entry[@"videos"]);
    NSString *urlString = entry[@"videos"][@"standard_resolution"][@"url"];
    NSLog(urlString);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player.view setFrame: CGRectMake(10, 65, 299, 299)];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: player.view];
    player.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [player play];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to retain your instance to `MPMoviePlayerController` i.e. as a property or an `instance` variable. The reference to the movie player is lost if you do not retain.

Answer (score 0):

When we try to load the video from URL initially it will display blank screen only. MPMoviePlayerController will take some time to load the video from url.So we can display first frame of the video till the video loads. For this need to import two frameworks.

1.AVFoundation

2.AssetsLibrary

Using these two we can display first frame of video into UIImageView as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t50.2886-16/11179443_819874424728492_389701720_n.mp4"];

AVAsset *avAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];

if ([[avAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] count] > 0)
{
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator =[AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:avAsset];
    Float64 durationSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds([avAsset duration]);
    CMTime midpoint = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(durationSeconds/2.0, 600);
    NSError *error;
    CMTime actualTime;

    CGImageRef halfWayImage = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:kCMTimeZero actualTime:&actualTime error:&error];

    if (halfWayImage != NULL)
    {

        NSString *actualTimeString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CMTimeCopyDescription(NULL, actualTime));
        NSString *requestedTimeString = (NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(CMTimeCopyDescription(NULL, midpoint));
        NSLog(@"Got halfWayImage: Asked for %@, got %@", requestedTimeString, actualTimeString);

        UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:halfWayImage];
        _imgVw.image=img;

    }

}


UITapGestureRecognizer *tap=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped)];
[_imgVw addGestureRecognizer:tap];




}


-(void)tapped
{
MPMoviePlayerController *movPlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[movPlayer setContentURL:url];
[movPlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
[movPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, _imgVw.frame.size.width, 250)];
[movPlayer prepareToPlay];
movPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
movPlayer.fullscreen = NO;
movPlayer.shouldAutoplay=YES;
[movPlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
[_imgVw addSubview:movPlayer.view];

[movPlayer play];


}
```

Here i am taking UIImageView view for playing the video. In viewDidLoad i am loading the 1st frame and giving tap gesture to the UIImageView. When i tapped the ImageView then i am playing the video.